# Opening GETH Websocket to Specific IP (remote connection)

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ubuntu, firewalls

I'm trying to connect to a GETH node of mine from a different location.  Currently I'm using the following settings:

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --maxpeers 100 --cache 32000  --txpool.pricebump 1 --ws --ws.api="eth,net" --ws.origins "*"
```

I'm using the origins "*" for testing purposes as I will replace it with specific IP addresses if I can get this to work.

I'm running UFW firewall in Ubuntu.  I've opened ports 8546:

```
sudo ufw allow 8546
```

However, running any web3 call from a different location to the IP address of the node (including the 8546 port) gives error: Error: connection not open on send().  This tells me the node is not connecting.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've noticed adding --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" enables me to connect remotely.  However, when adding a specific IP to wsorigins, I am still able to connect from any other IP.